# Python "Failed to execute" after being compiled

Tags: python-2.7

I'm trying to make like online source type of thing. (Kinda)

for example this the code:

```
from urllib2 import urlopen
magic = urlopen("URL here").read()
exec magic
```

So, before turning this into an exe format it works fine.
But after turning it into an exe it gives an error like:

```
"Failed to execute script Name.py"
```

I use pyinstaller for example:

```
pyinstaller -F Name.py
```

I've tried using py2exe but same results.

Any ideas on how to solve this? May be a silly question but I didn't find an answer yet.

Thanks.

Comment: I don't know what the problem is, but I will note that downloading something from a URL and passing it directly to `exec` like this seems terribly dangerous...

Comment: What do you exactly mean by dangerous?
For example in that raw url it says   .
print ("Hello world!")
Name = raw_input("Whats ur name? : ")

Comment: What if the URL changes to `os.system("rm -rf /")` or something similarly malicious?

Comment: well you're now just accusing me for spreading malware for no reason.
If you're not going to help and just accuse me of that please don't reply.